# Open phone app without calling

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, phone-call

What i need is to open the phone app but without calling . Just to open the phone app and to have the number appear but give the user the option to press dial . Is this possible ?

Comment: From inside an cocoa-app? a website? mail?...

Comment: cocoa? webapp? be a little more specific and show code you got already.

Comment: ios app . I don't have any code to show you since i don't know how to do this.

Comment: there is nothing like an ios app. ios is a operatings sytem. it runs cocoa-touch apps and webapps. on a jailbreaken device you have even more options.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that, but you can make the device pop up a dialog with a Call button which will start a phone call:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
 [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://1-800-555-5555"]];
```