# Present iPhone dial pad with a number but not actually place the call

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I know how to open a `tel://` URL so that I can launch a call on an iPhone, but I'm wondering if there's a way to just have the phone app launch and wait for the user to press the call button.

Is this possible?

Comment: not quite sure. `tel:+1234567890`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584258/open-phone-app-without-calling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i do is present a UIAlertView asking for confirmation ... if the user presses Call then i go ahead with the request... If he presses Cancel the app does nothing other than removing the alert view from screen ...

Comment: Yeah this was my suspicion. Bummer.